# make a full matrix output in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, python-2.x

I have a matrix with 236 x 97 dimension. When I print the matrix in Python its output isn't complete, having `.......` in the middle of matrix.

I tried to write the matrix to a test file, but the result is exactly same.
I can't post the screenshot because my reputation is not enough, and won't appear correctly if I choose another markup option.
Can anyone solve this?

---

```
 def build(self):
    self.keys = [k for k in self.wdict.keys() if len(self.wdict[k]) > 1]
    self.keys.sort()
    self.A = zeros([len(self.keys), self.dcount])
    for i, k in enumerate(self.keys):
        for d in self.wdict[k]:
            self.A[i,d] += 1

 def printA(self):
    outprint = open('outputprint.txt','w')
    print 'Here is the weighted matrix'
    print self.A
    outprint.write('%s' % self.A)
    outprint.close()
    print self.A.shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your matrix is an numpy array you can use `matrix.tofile(<options>)` to write the array to a file as documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np

# create a matrix of random numbers and desired dimension
a = np.random.rand(236, 97)

# write matrix to file
a.tofile('output.txt', sep = ' ')
```

Comment: it's actually work, but the value of the output is different with the output that I print in python shell. do i miss something ?

Comment: @IrfanDary: What exactly do you mean by 'is different'? The output on `stdout ` is shortended, actually. If I solved your problem, could you please tick my answer?

Comment: I mean the value is different with the output in the shell. I've take one value from text file, then i search that value in the shell, but the same value is'nt found .

Comment: @IrfanDary: I am not sure, but maybe this is due to reduced [precision on `stdout`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)? To proof this, double-check a value from the shell with a value from the output file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're specifically saving the `str` representation to a file with this line:

> `outprint.write('%s' % self.A)`

Which explicitly casts it to a string (`%s`) --- generating the abridged version you're seeing.

There are lots of ways to write the entire matrix to output, one easy option would be to use [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), for example:

```
import numpy
numpy.savetxt('outputprint.txt', self.A)
```

Comment: is it compatible with 2.7 version or I should import something from numpy ?
because its become error when i try this. it say "NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined"

Comment: @IrfanDary you have to import the `numpy` module first --- I've added the relevant line to my answer.  All module must be imported before they can be used.  Check out [this simple tutorial on modules](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm) if you're interested